# For MudBlazor component MudSelect, how do I get selected value to align in the center?

Tags: css, blazor-server-side, .net-6.0, mudblazor

I have a very simple drop down, a `MudSelect`, which is working fine.  When you list the choices they align fine in the middle, but I do not know how to get the selected value to align in the middle.  If I set `Style="text-align: center"` on the `MudSelect` itself, the selected value is still aligned to the left.  This does not look very nice on a wide device.

```
    <MudSelect @bind-Value="NumberOfRounds" T="int" Variant="Variant.Outlined" AnchorOrigin="Origin.CenterCenter">
        <MudSelectItem T="int" Value="1" Style="text-align: center"/>
        <MudSelectItem T="int" Value="2" Style="text-align: center"/>
        <MudSelectItem T="int" Value="3" Style="text-align: center"/>
        <MudSelectItem T="int" Value="4" Style="text-align: center"/>
        <MudSelectItem T="int" Value="5" Style="text-align: center"/>
        <MudSelectItem T="int" Value="6" Style="text-align: center"/>
        <MudSelectItem T="int" Value="7" Style="text-align: center"/>
        <MudSelectItem T="int" Value="8" Style="text-align: center"/>
        <MudSelectItem T="int" Value="9" Style="text-align: center"/>
        <MudSelectItem T="int" Value="10" Style="text-align: center"/>
    </MudSelect>
```

Does anyone know how to align the selected value in the center for this component?  I have read through [the API documentation](https://mudblazor.com/components/select#api), but I still don't understand how to do it (and my CCS skills are limited).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add a CSS class that targets the `input` tag inside your `MudSelect` component and assign the text alignment through there.

## Example

Here's a modified version of your code:

```
<style>
    .center-mud-dropdown input {
        text-align: center;
    }
</style>

<MudSelect class="center-mud-dropdown" @bind-Value="NumberOfRounds" T="int" Variant="Variant.Outlined" AnchorOrigin="Origin.CenterCenter" Style="text-align: center">
    <MudSelectItem T="int" Value="1" Style="text-align: center"/>
    <MudSelectItem T="int" Value="2" Style="text-align: center"/>
    <MudSelectItem T="int" Value="3" Style="text-align: center"/>
    <MudSelectItem T="int" Value="4" Style="text-align: center"/>
    <MudSelectItem T="int" Value="5" Style="text-align: center"/>
    <MudSelectItem T="int" Value="6" Style="text-align: center"/>
    <MudSelectItem T="int" Value="7" Style="text-align: center"/>
    <MudSelectItem T="int" Value="8" Style="text-align: center"/>
    <MudSelectItem T="int" Value="9" Style="text-align: center"/>
    <MudSelectItem T="int" Value="10" Style="text-align: center"/>
</MudSelect>

@code {
    private int NumberOfRounds { get; set; }
}
```

https://try.mudblazor.com/snippet/QaGcYIPIhHGGYjhU